# what distribution is more accurate describe the incomes of the average persons if we are not exclude the few persons of hundred billionaire?

Tags: statistics

Manhattan’s average weekly wages edged down to 2,448, yet remained the highest among the nation’s largest counties, those with 75,000 or more jobs. Queens led the remaining New York City boroughs with a weekly wage of 894, which was 10 percent below the national average of $989.

Sources: http://www.bls.gov/ro2/qcew9310.htm

It is assuming that the top 1 percent rich in US make the Manhatten's average income more than double times from the Queens.

My professor want us to think about the following question or discuss with friends to prepare for the next class.

So, what are some biased distributions that are more accurate describe the average incomes of the average persons if we are not exclude the few persons of hundred billionaire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link has a link to table 2. Table 2 has the following information:

Total employed (2,403,900) and their average income ($2,744).

Financial employed (348,100) and their average income ($7,659).

2403900*2744 - 348100*7659 is the income for all but the financial class

2403900 - 348100 are the employed not in the financial class.

Divide and you get an average ($1,912)